# Access SQLAlchemy model linked with foreign key

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a model with a foreign key to another model.  I query the first model, and want to access the model related to it.  In Django I can access the model from the foreign key.  How do I do this in SQLAlchemy?

```
class Model(Base):
    field_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Model2.id'))

class Model2(Base):
    id = Column(Integer)
    needed_field = Column(Integer)
```

```
models = Model.query.all()
return render to template('templ.html', models=models)
```

Django works like this:

```
models = Model.objects.all()
model.field_id.needed_field # loop in template
```

Comment: I think you should read about backref and relationship [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Django, defining the foreign key defines the column as well as the relationship to the other model.  In SQLAlchemy, you need to define both manually.  See the docs about [defining relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html).

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Group.id))
    group = db.relationship(Group, backref='users')

db.create_all()
db.session.add(User(group=Group()))
db.session.commit()
u = User.query.get(1)
print(u.group)
```

`User.group_id` is the foreign key pairing a `User` with a `Group`.  `User.group` is the relationship (and `Group.users` is the relationship in the other direction).  Usually you set and read the relationship, not the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Below example can help you

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

Now You can access parent child from parent_obj.children

For more details http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one